# std::condition_variable::notify_one: does it wake multiple threads if some have false predicate?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a ring buffer that is used for read/writers.  I keep track of the number if entries in the ring buffer and do not allow overwriting entries that have not been read.  I use std::condition_variable wait() and notify_one() to synchronize the readers and writers.  Basically the condition on the reader is that the number of entries > 0.  The condition on the writers is that the number of entries < capacity.

It all seems to work but there is one thing I don't understand.  When a reader or writer calls notify_one(), it does not cause a context switch.  I've read and understand that it works this way.  However, in a case where a writer writes an entry to fill the buffer, the writer calls notify_one() and continues to write another in which case its predicate fails in its wait().  In this case I see that another writer() may wake up and its predicate will fail as well.  Then a reader will wake up and its predicate succeeds and it can begin reading.

What I don't understand it why on one notify_one() multiple threads are being unblocked.  Does a wait() with a failed predicate not eat up the notify?   I can't find anything that states this is the case.

I could call notify_all() just to be sure but it seems to be working with notify_one().

Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>


// ring buffer with protection for overwrites 
template <typename T>
class ring_buffer {

  public:

    ring_buffer(size_t size) {
        cb.set_capacity(size);
    }

    void read(T& entry) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_mutex);
            cv.wait(lk, [this] {
                    std::cout << "read woke up, test=" << (cb.size() > 0) << std::endl; 
                    return 0 < cb.size();});
            auto iter = cb.begin();
            entry = *iter;
            cb.pop_front(); 
            std::cout << "Read notify_one" << std::endl;
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    } 

    void write(const T& entry) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_mutex);
            //std::cout << "Write wait" << std::endl;
            cv.wait(lk, [this] {
                    std::cout << "write woke up, test=" << (cb.size() < cb.capacity()) << std::endl; 
                    return cb.size() < cb.capacity();});
            cb.push_back(entry);
            std::cout << "Write notify_one" << std::endl;
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }

    size_t get_number_entries() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_mutex);
        return cb.size();
    }

  private:

    boost::circular_buffer<T> cb;
    std::condition_variable cv;
    std::mutex cv_mutex;
};

void write_loop(ring_buffer<int> *buffer) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        buffer->write(i);
    }
}

void read_loop(ring_buffer<int> *buffer) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; ++i) {
        int val;
        buffer->read(val);
    }

}

int main() {

    ring_buffer<int> buffer(1000); 
    std::thread writer(write_loop, &buffer);
    std::thread reader(read_loop, &buffer);
    std::thread reader2(read_loop, &buffer);

    writer.join();
    reader.join();
    reader2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

I see the following in the output where multiple threads are awoken because the predicate is false.

```
read woke up, test=0 
read woke up, test=0 
write woke up, test=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing the initial test of the condition when each of your read threads checks if it should wait, or if the condition is already met.

From [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait), this overload of wait() is equivalent to

```
while (!pred()) {
    wait(lock);
}
```

So wait() is only called when the condition is `true`, but the condition must be checked first.

```
read woke up, test=0  // tests condition on reader1 thread, false, wait is called
read woke up, test=0  // tests condition on reader2 thread, false, wait is called
write woke up, test=1 // tests condition on writer thread, true, wait is not called
```

[This](https://ideone.com/a3vsyD) might make it obvious where 2 values are written and each reader will only read a single value.

Comment: I understand that the condition runs the first time and if it fails then it will wait() and continue to do so.  However, if I create one thread that never returns true (Read2) then I see it periodically getting a notify and waiting.  I would think retrieving this notify would eat up the notify and no other thread would catch it but I see that each time this happens others get notified again.  Example:
`12035 Read woke up, test=0
12036 Read2 woke up, test=0
12037 Write woke up, test=1`

Comment: possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup ? - seems to work for me indefinitely on visual studio 2019 with out any false wakeups